# Internet Explorer cursor: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cursor

I have a wrapper div that contains all of my content.  I want this wrapper div to have a `cursor: pointer` because it's clickable, but I don't want the content inside the wrapper to have that cursor pointer:

[image]

So I set the wrapper to `cursor: pointer`, and the content div to `cursor: auto`, and it works fine...in everything except **Internet Explorer** (I'm using IE11). The problem in IE is that cursor: auto doesn't reset the cursor to its default state for each element, but instead sets it to the parent's cursor setting. (see [cursor:auto behaviour in IE 8 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800162/cursorauto-behaviour-in-ie-8-and-9)).  So in IE, I always see a pointer and it makes it seem like the whole page is clickable.

The problem with the solution in the answer I linked to is that even if I set the content area to have `cursor: default`, which turns the pointer cursor to a normal cursor, when I hover over text I don't get a text cursor, rather a normal, default one.  Is there any obvious solution to this problem aside from specifying each element manually inside the content div to have its default cursor? In other words:

```
.wrapper {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
    cursor: default;
}

.content p, .content h1, .content h2.... {
    cursor: text;
}

.content a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your layout like this, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/45/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="left">

    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="middle">

  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="right">

    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.middle {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I can't change the layout.  It's just wrapper > content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the * selector:

```
.content > * {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it even sets text elements (p, h1, etc) to have cursor default, which is an arrow instead of the vertical line looking cursor.  The only solution I can think of is to set each and every text element in content to have `cursor: text`, but that hardly seems like a good solution.